# Mac application uses more than 167% cpu

Tags: macos, process, cpu-usage

Is that bad an application uses 167% of cpu where the application do the following.

- Video previewing application which simultaneously show up to 32 cameras in live.
- Used boost library to communicate with camera and each camera connected with different thread.
- Used ffmpeg to decode the video data received from the camera and showing in image view.

**System specification**

- Mac Mini.
- 1.4 GHZ intel core i5
- RAM 4GB

Answer (score 1):

No, this is perfectly fine. 100% CPU usage simply means one core is completely used. (Or I guess 2 cores are at 50% use, but that is much less frequent).

With an Intel Core i5 you likely have 2 or 4 cores, possibly with hyper-threading (I don't know much about the i5s in mac minis). Because of this, a single process can use up to either 200% to 400% of a CPU, because you have either 2 or 4 logical cores.

As your program is using Boost and processing each camera in an individual thread, it is unsurprising that your program is using more then one core. Hence, seeing a CPU usage of 167% is perfectly fine and reasonable.